# Compiling NakedMUD on OS X 10.9.2

Tags: python, macos, compilation

I have a little problem with compiling NakedMUD on my Mac. I think, I added all the right directories to the module.mk file now, so it looks like this:

```
# the top level directory of python.
PYTHONTOP = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

# the folder where python headers are located
C_FLAGS  += -I$(PYTHONTOP)/Headers

# libraries we have to include.
LIBS     += -u _PyMac_Error -lm -ldl -lutil -L/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7
```

But when I try to compile with 'make', I get the following errors:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/lib/python2.7/config'
ld: library not found for -lpython2.7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I tried googling the problem, but most answers I found were about configuring Xcode...but I am using the terminal.
I am sorry, if this sounds a bit stupid but I really tried everything that I could and am not very experienced. I would be very glad if somebody could tell me what's wrong.

Best wishes,
Aerdureth

Comment: You are missing config file for the python version as the warning informs you. Does python2.7/config exist anywhere?

Comment: It does. I got that path via 'find . -name "libpython*a" -print' when I went to the path used as PYTHONTOP.

Comment: Well then you have to pass that path to compiler with -I option, for example -I /usr/include/python2.7/  and it should word.

Comment: Ah, thank you :) I changed the path as suggested and it's finding the file now. Though now, something different happened: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyInt_Check", referenced from:
      _extenderDoOptChoice in olc_extender.o
  "__Py_FalseStruct", referenced from:
      _cmdTryChecks in command.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation

Comment: You also have to pass the proper path to linker, as if GCC didn't find it then linker will also struggle.